# AWS docker image is not updating the content in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I use jenkins to pull the code, create the images, push them to ECR, update the task-definitions and then force the deployments of the new images in ECS. All this has been working fine for several months, until this week when suddenly the new images do not have the new code.

I have verified this by entering the images and seeing that the code base is the same as the last version. The weirdest thing is that when I pull that same image from ECR on my machine and access the code it is the new one.

I have also tried removing all the docker images in the ECR private repository and launching a new machine. Nonetheless, it was able to launch again with the old code even though there were no images in ECR. That is why I think the issue may be related to something related to caching. I have little knowledge of cloud and architecture which is why I have not been able to go further.

Comment: Are you reusing the same docker tag like `latest`? If so, caching is an issue and you should use a unique tag for each release/deployment.

Comment: Can you add snippet of your jenkinsfile into the question, so we can help

Comment: yes I think that was it, combined with the EC2 running out of memory to pull the new images once that was changed

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was caching. It worked for me by building images with --no-cache and pushing the updated images to ECR.

```
docker compose build --no-cache
```